# Calculate RGB Values

Tags: algorithm, colors, color-picker

I am currently coding a [colorpicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ciib.png) and trying to create a function 
that takes 3 integers between 0 and 255 (RGB).

[image: Colorpicker]

If you look at the image linked above, you can see that there is a rainbow-gradient in the center. All RGB values on there contain at least one integer that is 0 and one that is 255. The other one can be anything between 0 and 255. Then you have a square on the left in the image that contains a gradient of all "sub-colors" of this "rainbow-color".

The function should take the RGB values of this sub-color (for example R = 112, G = 158, B = 73 which is a kind of greenish color)
and get me the rainbow-color (R = 116, G = 255, B = 0 notice the 255, 0 and the value in between).

I really tried to develop an algorythm to solve this problem for me but im just getting really rough estimations of the rainbow-color. I know that its not possible to, for example, get the rainbow-color by R = 19, G = 19, B = 18 because there are a lot of rainbow-colors that contain these values. But there should be a way to get this about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gradient corresponds to color attribute `hue` or `chroma` value in HSL/HSV [color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

So to build needed picture, you can make gradient bar with hue varying in range 0..360 and max saturation.

When user picks hue value, fill a square with colors using same hue but all possible `saturation` and `luminance` values.

Linked page also gives formulas for HSL-RGB (and backward) converting. Note that some graphics libraries and frameworks already contain functions for such convertation.

Comment: Yeah that works! I converted the RGB to HSL and kept the hue, set the saturation to max and the luminance in the middle. Very nice Solution. Thank you